# How to copy contents of a file in AWS ec2 to a variable using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS. Is there a way to read the contents of a file located in AWS EC2 and store it in a variable so that i can use it to encode the contents.
I have written the encode script already.

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{

         String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path to file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(text.getBytes());
System.out.println(encodedString);
    
     }  
}
```

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: The Java code is running on the EC2 instance, correct? If so, the fact that you are using EC2 (or AWS at all) would seem to be entirely irrelevant.

Comment: The code you show already reads from a file and encodes the contents. What's not working?

Comment: Hi  :  im trying to run a ci maven project from github actions. So i need to access the file first then then use my encode to encode it. The confusion is how will i access the file from aws. I hope i make sense
If i use it from github actions, the code runs on aws, can  directly access the file?

Comment: Your issue is not with accessing ec2, but with accessing a file on a remote machine. you should use a file transfer protocol like ftp or scp etc..

Comment: @YogevCaspi: the file is in ec2 and im trying to access that using java through github actions

Comment: again, its not relevant,its still a remote machine, and to extract a file from it you should use ftp or something similar.

Comment: The easier process would be to NOT have the file on the EC2 instance, since it is difficult to access another computer on the Internet (regardless of whether it is an EC2 instance). Could you, instead, put the file in an Amazon S3 bucket? Perhaps the EC2 instance could upload the file to S3 whenever it is changed, so that it is accessible to you? Definitely try to avoid having to "reach into" another computer on the Internet.

Comment: I agree with @JohnRotenstein , accessing the ec2 instance files should be avoided.